# File Explorer - Drag and Drop disabled (Move) - Windows 10

Tags: windows-explorer, drag-and-drop

How can I fix the issue of not being able to drag and drop files from one directory to another in windows 10, using the file explorer. There is a prohibition which was not there before, I am not sure what is preventing this functionality from not happening.

[image: file explorer - drag and drop disabled]

Comment: Is the Quick Access feature enabled/working fine? If you've applied a registry tweak that disables Quick access via the registry, it might break the drag-drop functionality in the Explorer navigation pane.

Comment: Where are you trying to drag it to? The highlighted option doesn't appear to be a folder. Try two separate windows, source & destination.

Comment: You might need to try a new USER Account.  I amended my answer to include this possibility.

Comment: My machine has no problem doing what you show in your screenshot.  A 3rd party shell extension or a problem with your profile can break this functionality in addition to all of the other recommendations.  They can wreak havoc on the explorer's intended functionality.   I would start with @John answer and work your way out from there.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix the issue of not being able to drag and drop files from
> one directory to another .....  I am not sure what is preventing this
> functionality from not happening.

Two repairs to try:

**(A) DISM and SFC**

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online
> /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online
> /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all
> the above is complete and test.

**(B) Windows 10 Repair Install.**

If DISM and SFC steps do not solve the problem, run the Windows 10 Repair Install

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run.
>
> Use the option to Keep Everything.

**(C) Try New User account to see if Drag and Drop works in a new account.**

There are more aggressive options available if Keep Everything does not work.

You would the most aggressive option (Keep Nothing) if your USER Profile is damaged. You can determine if your USER Profile is damaged by creating a new USER Account and see if Drag and Drop works in a new USER Account.

Be very sure to back everything up first.